# System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices Error in Mono

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mono

I have a mature C# application that has always been run on Windows that is being ported to Linux (on Mono), and I am running into an error that I cannot resolve regarding PluralizationServices in System.Data.Entity.Design.

The line of code causing the problems is as follows:

```
PluralizationService pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Although this has never caused any problems on the Windows application running under Microsoft.NET, when the program is running under Mono I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

I found [here](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/System-Data-Entity-Design-PluralizationServices-reference-location-td4658036.html) someone else who seemed to be having a similar problem had simply copied the .NET version of the .dll over to their Mono project, and it resolved the issue for them. I tried the same, however I then encountered the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MudSharp.Framework.LanguageHelpers ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService:CreateService (System.Globalization.CultureInfo): method body is empty.
```

I'm using Mono 3.10 on Ubuntu. I can't find any suggestion that Mono doesn't support these functions, and I'm simply unsure how to proceed with debugging this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you wait for [EF7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx)? The release data is not known yet...

Comment: If it would fix the problem I am having, then it may be the only choice. However, I would like to understand why I am having the problem and if it is possible to fix it first of all though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like latter versions of Mono do support the PluralizationService - see [function support status](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Data.Entity.Design).

However, the PluralizationService currently only supports [English](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.createservice(v=vs.110).aspx).

Have you tried this:

```
PluralizationService pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));`
```

FYI, looks easy enough to extend to other languages using the  EntityModelSchemaGenerator class.

Answer (score 2):

- [Plurally](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Plurally)  is a Mono-compatible replacement to the Entity Framework pluralization services.
- use Plurally test library source code [jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/)
- IDE: Xamarin Studio 6.1.3
- framework: Mono / .NET 4.5
- add NuGet package: Newtonsoft.Json, Plurally
- JsonClassGenerator.cs line 10,39
- use Plurally.Pluralizer

  ```
  using Plurally;
  private Pluralizer pluralizationService = new Pluralizer(new CultureInfo("en-us"));
  ```
- JsonType.csline 8

  ```
  using Plurally;
  ```
- Xamasoft.JsonClassGenerator.JsonClassGenerator GenerateClasses Result

  ```
  {
      "UserAccount": "",
      "UserPassword": "",
      "ExtraInfo": ""
  }
  ```

  ```
  // Generated by Xamasoft JSON Class Generator
  // http://www.xamasoft.com/json-class-generator
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
  namespace CommonModels
  {
      public class loginArgs
      {
          public string UserAccount { get; set; }
          public string UserPassword { get; set; }
          public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: [Stack Overflow generally works in English](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating the parts that aren't in English.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Chinese is remove，i test that package is enable.